# Re-topology Strategy Needed for Complex Organic Model

Tags: modeling, retopology

Problem: How to conceptualize a strategy for re-topologizing a complex organic shape (e.g. morel mushroom) in Blender 3.6

I sculpted this morel mushroom and now I need to create a re-topologized mesh. I am fairly new to re-topology, but I can do pretty well on both geometric and simple organic  shapes, but the fact that this model is comprised of many different sized organic shapes has me stumped.

I have tried several strategies, none of which has worked, as I keep modeling myself into corners. For example, I've tried making all the circles the same vertex count (even numbers) or giving all the large ones, say, 32 vertices and the small ones 12 or 16, and attaching them together. I have also tried making vertical rows of quads between the circles and attaching them that way. I know there is a mathematical solution to this problem, but I suck at math.

My goals are the following:
To have all or mostly quads of relatively same sizes and clear routes to creating seams.
The end product should be a well defined, but reasonably low-poly model that isn't a headache to unwrap and paint in an external editor like Krita.
To accomplish this using only built-in add-ons like Bsurfaces.

So my question is, for those of you who have experience re-topologizing complex organic shapes:

1. How would you approach this project?
2. At what point would you break rules and use odd numbers of verts & triangles instead of quads?

I have attached the file (see link below,) which contains the sculpted mesh, and a Bsurfaces mesh, with some work done that exemplifies the problems I am having. I would be grateful for any constructive advice, and possibly, this will also help someone else. Thanks.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ceFyhIPzScN0yVi0Xsb6n0lSCzrCsXw2?usp=sharing

Comment: This question, imo, is too broad. Not trying to be unhelpful, but this can be tackeled in many different ways according to the situation and the person who is modelling.

Comment: What do you plan to do with your object? Maybe retopologizing is not worth it. If you don't need to take any close-up shot, you could create a very low-poly version (without the holes) and bake the normals of the high-poly to fake the holes. Apart from that you could try the remesh tools of Blender but it will stay rather high-poly if you don't want any artefact.

Comment: Thanks, @ The Kalaakar, & @ moonboots both your comments are helpful. 

@ The Kalaakar, I think I am just trying to get some insight into different ways to look at this problem. Maybe a better question is  "how to connect multiple organic shapes of different sizes & vertex counts with quads." 
As @ moonboots has pointed out, I may need to re-consider what I am trying to accomplish. Ultimately, I want a nice morel mushroom to go into my mushroom assets collection, but maybe I don't need to bang my head against the wall.

Comment: Hello, @ChuctanundaSpiderbone The K. is right. This question is too broad as  it stands, and risks being closed. I think it can be rescued, though, by making it shorter, and less abstract. Just make it a post about this particular case, with a screen-grabbed illustration, so folks can have a look before downloading, and preferably a share on https://blend-exchange.com/ . I don't think you have to worry.. the general principles will emerge from the particular case.

Comment: It all depends on what your asset is for, if the mushroom will be part of alarge setup, you can make a very low-poly with a normal map to fake the holes, if you want to make some close-up shots of your object it will need to be high-poly and you'll need to either retopologize like you're doing right now, or use a remesh tool, but you won't be able to be very low poly if you want to keep some rather sharp edges for your holes

Comment: Thank you, Robin Betts and moonboots for your helpful commentary. I am new to Stack Exchange, and this will help me target my questions in future. Also, I didn't know about blend-exchange, so this has been very helpful. I will retire my question for now, as being too broad for one concise answer. I thank you all for your help and patience.